# Maven TestNG project not executing from command prompt

Tags: testng

When  I try to run project from project from command prompt I have Main Menu Test Cases have been failed exception.

> java -cp
>   C:\Users\eclipse-workspac\CTv_Web_Auto_Check\bin;C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\CTv_Web_Auto_Check\lib*
>   org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

[image]

Comment: add your error stacktrace

Comment: @user7294900 my project run in eclipse without any issue when i try to run through command prompt its faling

Comment: try mvn clean install from the command line

Comment: im facing when i try to run mvn clean install command, how can i solve this  Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: You must run the 'mvn clean install' in the path where the pom.xml file located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add in Your pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and in dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Try following commands in command line to run Your tests:

**1. run all testclasses inside maven project**

```
mvn test
```

**2. running single test:**

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClassName#testCaseName test
```

**3. runningalltests(in class):**

```
mvn -Dtest=TestClassName test
```

**4. (if using testNg) running via testsuite**

```
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/java/com/testsuites/testsuitAll.xml test
```

I think You should use the last one (4.) with first referencing on Your project path.

Hope this helps,